Intel ARC equivalent for NvOptimusEnablement (Nvidia) & AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance (AMD)?
Intel Integrated+NVIDIA dual-GPU "Optimus" setups, an application can export NvOptimusEnablement as explained in OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf. This option allows an application to ensure the use of the high-speed discrete GPU without needing profile updates or user interaction, which is usually desired for certain classes of applictions.
AMD has a similar called AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance.
Is there an equivalent trick for systems with Intel ARC GPUs?
